# Get UNSAT Core using Z3 from .smt2 file

Tags: z3

I need to get unsat core from z3. The contents of .smt2 file are:
`(set-option :produce-unsat-cores true)
(set-logic QF_AUFBV )
(declare-fun a () (Array (_ BitVec 32) (_ BitVec 8) ) )
; Constraints
(! (assert (bvslt  (concat  (select  a (_ bv3 32) ) (concat  (select  a (_ bv2 32) ) (concat  (select  a (_ bv1 32) ) (select  a (_ bv0 32) ) ) ) ) (_ bv10 32) ) )
 :named ?U0)
(! (assert (bvslt  (_ bv10 32) (concat  (select  a (_ bv3 32) ) (concat  (select  a (_ bv2 32) ) (concat  (select  a (_ bv1 32) ) (select  a (_ bv0 32) ) ) ) ) ) )
 :named ?U1)
(check-sat)
(get-unsat-core)
(exit)`

I am getting the following output when running z3:
`unsupported
; !
unsupported
; !
sat
(error "line 11 column 15: unsat core is not available")`

 I am new to z3, can't understand what is happening here (I am sure that the expression is unsat).
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use `!` incorrectly. The exclamation point is used for naming formulae (not asserts). See section 3.9.8 from the [Tutorial](http://www.grammatech.com/resource/smt/SMTLIBTutorial.pdf).

This should fix it: `(assert (! (bvslt ...) :named ?U0))`.